# How can I pass Jenkins Filesystem list parameter selected value to the Execute shell

Tags: jenkins

I am using the Jenkins Filesystem list parameter plugin to get the list of file names present in a directory. I am getting the list of file names populated in the dropdown but I am not able to pass the selected value from the dropdown to Execute shell section.
Basically I want to pass the filename from the dropdown to the Maven command to execute the script.

I tried using the Name parameter to get the filename selected by user but its printing nothing.

Ex: Name of the parameter is set as "select" and in Shell, I tried echo $select but it prints nothing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The value of selection is always stored in the Name of the parameter, So you should be able to use it in Execute shell as a shell variable, in your case its like `$select`
 Example:
`echo "Selected file is $select"`
Same valid even for maven command case as well.

Comment: You are right even I thought the same even though the files that are present in the directory are visible properly in the dropdown but echo $select prints nothing. Just one doubt here is there any validation for file type or size bcoz my file is an apk file of around 50 to 100 MB?

Comment: strange why it does not work when you are echoing the variable. There is no such validation type based on file size. But plugin is providing `include` `exclude patterns` which could be used only at file name level.